# fmdb insert date gives "invalid date"

Tags: objective-c, ios, fmdb

I'm trying to use fmdb in my latest ios-project and it worked great so far. But now i'm trying to do inserts with an NSDate as a parameter and it ends up being stored as an invalid date in my sqlite database.
I have tried multiple solutions, but nothing seems to work. What am i doing wrong?

```
[database executeUpdate:@"CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS inspection (ID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, result TEXT, date_of_inspection DATE, restaurant_id INTEGER"];

NSDate *today=[NSDate date];
[database executeUpdate:@"insert into inspection(id,result,date_of_inspection,restaurant_id) values(?,?,?,?)",[inspection valueForKey:@"id"], result, today, [restaurant valueForKey:@"id"],nil];
```

The database is populated and everything works fine except for the *#%! date... :)
What is wrong?

Comment: What do you mean by "nothing seems to work"? Please be specific about what is stored as the date.

Answer (score 7):

[SQLite doesn't have a date format](http://sqlite.org/datatype3.html), so that FMDB expects the date fields to be stored as floats/real numbers:

```
else if ([obj isKindOfClass:[NSDate class]]) {
    sqlite3_bind_double(pStmt, idx, [obj timeIntervalSince1970]);
}
```

So try making your table with that format.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
[database executeUpdate:@"CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS inspection(ID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, result TEXT, date_of_inspection REAL, restaurant_id INTEGER"];

NSDate *today=[NSDate date];
[database executeUpdate:@"insert into inspection(id,result,date_of_inspection,restaurant_id) values(?,?,?,?)",[inspection valueForKey:@"id"], result, [today timeIntervalSince1970], [restaurant valueForKey:@"id"],nil];
```

SQLite does not support the DATE data type (http://www.sqlite.org/datatype3.html).
You must store it as a REAL data type. timeIntervalSince1970 returns the data type NSTimeInterval, which is a double (
https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/cocoa/reference/foundation/Miscellaneous/Foundation_DataTypes/Reference/reference.html).